# AngularJS - userService, registerControll: broken code in registerController, not registering user and returning wrong alert

Tags: java, javascript, angularjs, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

Here is my registerController:

```
collectionsApp.controller('registerController', function($scope, userService) {
    $scope.register = function() {
        userService.register($scope.user);
    };

});
```

Here is my serviceController:

```
collectionsApp.service('userService', function($http) {
    return {
        login : function(user) {
            $http.post('/user/login', user).then(function(data) {
                return data;
            });
        },
        register : function(user) {
            $http.post('/user/add', user).then(function(data) {
            });
        }

    };
});
```

When I hit interface button that has data-ng-click="register(user)" registration works just fine BUT when I want to add simple test feedback message responded from backend in data object and edit my registerController like this:

```
collectionsApp.controller('registerController', function($scope, userService) {
    $scope.register = function() {
        userService.register($scope.user);

    };
    userService.register = function(data) {
        if (data.status === "success") {
            alert("OK");
        } else {
            alert("NOT OK");
        }
    };
});
```

Now I am not able to register new (there are no new user written to db) but I get this "NOT OK" alert every time... Can someone help me fix and understand this mechanism? How to get this status, check it, and send it to view (redirect registered user to new page)?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: I am sending response as HashMap...

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting `userService.register` in controller so it no longer sends a request to server. What you want to do is to make use of promise pattern, i.g. `then` callback. Take a look:

```
collectionsApp.controller('registerController', function($scope, userService) {
    $scope.register = function() {
        userService.register($scope.user).then(function(data) {
            if (data.status === "success") {
                alert("OK");
            } else {
                alert("NOT OK");
            }
        });
    };
});
```

For this you also need to fix service method, make sure you *return* promise from it:

```
register: function(user) {
    return $http.post('/user/add', user);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, don't make changes to your registerController, but change your serviceController

```
collectionsApp.service('userService', function($http) {
    return {
    login : function(user) {
        $http.post('/user/login', user).then(function(data) {
            return data;
        });
    },
    register : function(user) {
        $http.post('/user/add', user).then(function(data) {
          if (data.status === "success") {
           alert("OK");
          } else {
           alert("NOT OK");
          }
        });
    }

};
});
```